# Codeigniter Version Upgradation - 2.1.4 to 3.1.11 in HMVC Structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, version, hmvc-codeigniter

In one of our Codeigniter Project we are facing issues while upgrading it's version from 2.1.4 to 3.1.11.
We have followed Codeigniter Official site to upgrade the version but as we have HMVC Structure that method is not working properly.

We have followed the method mentioned in these sites - https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html 
and https://www.chuongduong.net/ci3/installation/upgrade_300.html.

But by following both the sites and solving the errors after that we reached to the 404 error at last.

Can anyone please help us here? Anyone who has any idea about upgradation in HMVC structure.

Let me know if you need any information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

replace index.php file and add error folder from new downloaded Ci3 to location application/view/ in your project